# Android Studio is showing an error for a plugin that isn't installed

Tags: android, git, android-studio, plugins

Every time I start Android Studio I see this error relating to a plugin called Git Bar:

[image]

I remember installing this plugin in the past but when I view the installed plugins in Settings it isn't listed:

[image]

So how can I remove this plugin and resolve the error?

Comment: Try to remove the folder with the plugin name manually by going to  C:\Users\YOUR USER NAME\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by browsing to my Android Studio plugins folder and deleting the file **gitbar.jar**.

(In my case, because I install via the JetBrains Toolbox, the full path was `%LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\ch-0\201.7042882.plugins\gitbar.jar`.)